# M2e not finding missing repository - m2e eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

When I hover over a package that is not found within Eclipse and click 'Search repositories', the dependency I'm searching for is not found. The dependency exists on the official maven repository : http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/portlet/portlet-api/2.0-r12/portlet-api-2.0-r12.pom

Do I need to configure m2e to search the maven repository ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to type **portlet-api** instead cause the text on the dialog says "Select an artifact to add..."...

Comment: @khmarbaise ive tried that but same result. I can use an advanced search on http://search.maven.org/ but searching via eclipse would be nicer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to update your repository index in the Maven Repositories View.

1. Open the View with: `Windows -> Show View -> Others -> Maven -> Maven Repositories View`
2. Start `Rebuild Index` and/or `update Index` from the context menu of the Central Repository

This (long running) task is normally done on startup (Windows -> Preferences -> Maven ->Download Repository Index updates on startup) but maybe it is disabled to get a better eclipse startup performance.