# Can't get the latest version of a library

Tags: maven, netty, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm using Eclipse Juno SR1, and I think the integrated m2e plugin uses Maven 3 but I'm not sure.

Netty has recently published the 4.0.0.Beta1 version, but I can't seem to update it via Maven -- Eclipse's m2e plugin. I've opened the `pom.xml` file -> Dependencies tab -> Add -> searched for netty. It could only find the previous version 4.0.0.Alpha8.

I've tried updating (forcefully) the dependencies. I've tried manually delete the contents of the m2e's local (cache) repository directory and rebuilding the index from scratch. <strike>I've manually edited the `pom.xml`</strike> *This works now!* Still I can't download the latest version, even though it's clearly been published to the central repo [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg:%22io.netty%22).

EDIT: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122483/m2e-not-finding-missing-repository-m2e-eclipse-plugin) seems similar to mine. I've tried the solution provided by the answer (as mentioned above), but it didn't work.

EDIT: Ah! Indeed they've changed the artifactId from `netty` to `netty-all`! So, getting the latest version *manually* now works, but I still wish I could find it with the dependency search window thing.

Comment: Do you use Nexus as proxy?

Comment: What is exactly artifactId you are using. Add <dependency> declaration to this post.

Comment: (1) I'm unsure what that means. I use the default settings that came with Eclipse. (2) I've used the old artifactId that seems to have been changed from `netty` to `netty-all`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefully at artifactId. Maybe it was changed from Alpha to Betta.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.Beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

2) Create new Maven project and try to play and find out if you can't download other jars.
For me it worked for netty-common artifact.

Comment: Before I accept this answer, I'll ask whether you know why I couldn't find the newly added artifactId `netty-all` in the "add dependency window", but adding it manually to the `pom.xml` worked?

Comment: "add dependency window" will search in your local maven repository, not remote.

Comment: Yeah, but I forcefully updated (by manually deleting the local repo files and redownloading that ~90MB .gz file) my local maven repo. At least I thought I did.